# Как пользоваться платформой jMonkeyEngine?

Tags: разработка-игр, java, 3d

Как пользоваться платформой jMonkeyEngine? Что надо сделать, чтобы создать игру?

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php).

Читайте туториалы, русского сообщества нет, только английское.